# Parsing ONLY plain text from HTML using Kanna Swift

Tags: html, swift, parsing, xpath, html-parsing

I am using [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) Swift for HTML parsing.

For example:
How can I parse ONLY the highlighted English Text in this situation?

> To be **prone to** something, usually something bad, means to have
>   a tendency to be affected by it or to do it.

[image]

```
                <div class="caption hide_cn"> 
                    <a class="anchor" name="prone_1"></a>
                    <span class="num">1</span>
                    <span class="st" title="能被表示程度的副词或介词词组修饰的形容词">ADJ-GRADED </span>
                    <span class="tips_box">
                        <span class="lbl type-syntax">
                            <span class="span"> [</span>
                            verb-link <span class="hi rend-sc">ADJ</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="lbl type-syntax">
                            <span class="span">, </span>
                            <span class="hi rend-sc">ADJ</span>
                            to-infinitive
                            <span class="span">]</span>
                        </span>
                    </span> 
                    <span class="def_cn cn_before">
                        <span class="chinese-text">有（不好的）倾向的；易于</span>
                        …
                        <span class="chinese-text">的；很可能</span>
                        …
                        <span class="chinese-text">的</span>
                    </span> 
                    To be <b>prone to</b> something, usually something bad, means to have a tendency to be affected by it or to do it. 
                    <span class="def_cn cn_after">
                        <span class="chinese-text">有（不好的）倾向的；易于</span>
                        …
                        <span class="chinese-text">的；很可能</span>
                        …
                        <span class="chinese-text">的</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

If I use:
`doc.css("div[class='caption hide_cn']")`

I get all the messy part around the sentence I want.

Maybe I am wrong but I could not find enough documentation about the usage.
e.g. I learned`"span[class= 'xxx xxx']"` from stackoverflow instead of the documentation from that github page.
Do we have something like `"[class != 'xxx xxx'] "` or `!=span`

Comment: I don't think you can because this sentence is not delimited by tags. For example using Fuzi (similar to Kanna) the 5th child I get is `<span class="def_cn cn_before">` and the 6th is `<b>prone to</b>`. The parser apparently ignores the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @Moritz I am afraid so. Do you know any other lib/package can do this? even if it's not for Swift.

Comment: Fuzi is the best I know. But I'm not an expert at using it, so maybe I missed a way to parse this thing. Let's hope someone answers with a solution.

Comment: @Moritz, I found a solution, see below.

Answer (score 1):

After some tweaks, I found a work around solution, in case someone needs it later.

We can use the `removeChild` method to remove all the other sections!

```
// Search for nodes by CSS
      for whole in doc.css("div[class='caption hide_cn']") {
        if let a1 = doc.css("span[class='num']").first {
          whole.removeChild(a1)
        }
        if let a2 = doc.css("span[class='st']").first {
          whole.removeChild(a2)
        }
        if let a3 = doc.css("span[class='tips_box']").first {
          whole.removeChild(a3)
        }
        if let s1 = doc.css("span[class='def_cn cn_before']").first {
          whole.removeChild(s1)
        }
        if let s2 = doc.css("span[class='def_cn cn_after']").first {
          whole.removeChild(s2)
        }
        print(whole.text)
      }
```

It's a pity I could not find this in the documentation. I guess those packages/libs are powerful enough to do almost anything you want. You just need to tweak a little bit.